# Python, Selenium - handle multiple wait-conditions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a file called `webdriver.py` which implements methods from `selenium.webdriver` library. Had a wait-function that were handling most of the cases I need:

```
def wait_for(self, func, target=None, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    timeout = timeout or self.timeout
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(func)
    except TimeoutException:
        if not target:
            raise WebDriverException('Wait for: "%s" failed!' % inspect.getsource(func).strip())
        raise NoSuchElementException(target)
```

Where `func` is a selector.

The problem is that sometimes the DOM element would be invisible, causing exception and test failure. So I would like to extend `wait_for` to also wait for the element to become visible.

Something like

```
def wait_for(self, func, target=None, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    timeout = timeout or self.timeout
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(func)).until(func)
    except TimeoutException:
        if not target:
            raise WebDriverException('Wait for: "%s" failed!' % inspect.getsource(func).strip())
        raise NoSuchElementException(target)
```

`EC` is a `selenium.driver.expected_conditions`

This would not work of course - either `until().until()` syntax is not supported.. or something else happens, like `EC` doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EC.presence_of_element_located` for waiting an element in DOM to visible, no need for second `.until`.

```
def wait_for(self, func, target=None, timeout=self.timeout):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, func)))
    except TimeoutException:
        if not target:
            raise WebDriverException('Wait for: "%s" failed!' % inspect.getsource(func).strip())
        raise NoSuchElementException(target)
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I also used "from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC" to fix EC problem.

Comment: I also think it should be: "By.ByCssSelector" according to https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByCssSelector.html

Comment: @h3d0 it should be `By.CSS_SELECTOR ` for python check http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=by.css_selector#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CSS_SELECTOR

Comment: Indeed,`By.CSS_SELECTOR` it is.